# Dynamic routing in Next.js doesn't work (404 error)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I've just started with Next.js and I've already faced a problem with dynamic routing. For some reason it doesn't work although it should. I tried with folder and with file as well but it won't work. This is really cumbersome...
[image]

It just displays 404 error...

Comment: The `[meetupId]/index.js` and `[bomba].js` routes conflict with each other, you can't have both.

Answer (score 5):

In order for your dynamic routes to work and if you're using SSG, you need to make use of `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` functions to pre-render all the paths (and the content for each one as well) containing the `meetupId` param.

You can read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)

Comment: Yesssssssssssssss

Comment: in the page od dynamic routing i see no mention of that : https://next-site-4vixvljn1.vercel.sh/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

are we blind or the nextjs team is stupid?

Answer (score 0):

try to rename your index.js to page.js